# Appending data with unequal data frame dimensions

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, append

**What is the best way to append data using matching column names from two different data frames with differing dimensions?**

**Scenario:**

Df1 = 350(rows)x2778(columns)
Df2 = 321x2910

Df1 has <2778 columns with the exact same name as <2910 columns in Df2.
-It could be 500 columns in each data frame as an example that have equivalent names

**What I want to do:**

**Append data from df2 to df1 where the column names match.**
E.x.: df1's data is present in matching column and has df2's data appended to the end of the column, put underneath it so to say.

**If the col names don't match**, the data frame that lacks the matching name should have the name attached as a new column with NA's filling the missing space.
E.x.: df1 doesn't have a column df2 has, so the column is added while maintaining order of processing.

I've tried to do this using Pandas in Python but got Index duplication errors (probably the columns). I'm looking at R now but I want to know if anyone has a simple solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample code and data.

Comment: Concat should do the trick. `new_df=pd.concat([df1, df2])`

Comment: It will be ever so much easier to help you with your specific question if you can find a way to share some fake example data that demonstrates the general structure of your two data frames (a couple rows and columns may be enough) and what output you expect. This sounds like `rbind` or `dplyr::bind_rows` might do it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `merge()` from base r or `bind_rows()` from dplyr.

Comment: dplyr::bind_rows() did it!